# Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) : '.' in formula and no 'data' argument

Tags: r, gwidgets, gui-toolkit

i created a GUI for regression analysis.

svalue(tbl[2,1]) : accept a .csv input file

svalue(tbl[4,1]) : provide a dependent variable

```
enter code here


selected_var=read.csv(svalue(svalue(tbl[2,1]))
sv=selected_var

sv_regression=data.frame(sv)
glm1<<-glm(svalue(tbl[4,1]) ~ . ,data = sv_regression,family = poisson)
reg<<-summary.glm(glm1)$coefficients

reg_result <<-gtable(reg)
add(frame1,reg_result,expand=TRUE)
```

now run this code, i got an error

Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) : 
  '.' in formula and no 'data' argument

Comment: Where is the `svalue()` function from?  `read.csv(svalue(svalue(...)))` looks particularly odd... Why are you hard assigning things to upstream environments (`<<-`) which is nearly always bad practice?

Answer (score 1):

`glm()` and other modelling functions need a formula in this structure:

`glm(var1 ~ ., data = sv_regression, family = poisson)

Where `var1` should be the name of the response variable you are trying to predict.  Without knowing what `tbl` and `svalue` are I can't see exactly what's going wrong (I suspect at least three things), but you need to structure your data in a way that you know in advance the name of the variable to be on the left side of the formula in your statistical model.

For example, given you are dependent on the user choosing things in the GUI, you could rename the column in `sv_regression` that is to be the response variable as `y` (or something more distinctive that has less chance of causing a conflict with an existing name), before you call `glm`.  Then when you call `glm` you know that it will by `glm(y ~ ., ...)`